# Palindrome function in python not returning expected results

Tags: python, for-loop, palindrome

Trying to define a palindrome function with a for loop as follows:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    for i in input_string.lower(): 
        if input_string.strip():
            new_string = new_string.join(reverse_string)
            reverse_string = reverse_string.join(new_string)
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False
```

```
print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

I keep getting all True. Can anyone uncover why that is?

Comment: Just use reverse_string = reversed(input_string),if list(input_string) == list(reverse_string): return True return False.

Comment: join does not do at all what you think it does

Comment: Your `for` loop makes no sense whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are iterating over the `input_string` but you are not using the variable `i` also it does not make sense to use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in the way you are trying to do, seems like you have an idea but using the wrong tooling

to check if `input_string` is palindrome you could use :

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    l = input_string.lower().replace(' ', '')
    return l == l[::-1]


print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even"))
print(is_palindrome("abc"))
print(is_palindrome("kayak"))
```

output:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as to why OP's code is not working.

Comment: That's a really elegant way of putting it. Way better than what I was going for. Thanks